# What should I do if on the 29 Shaban the sky is cloudy and I cannot see the Crescent of Shahri Ramadan?

Tags: ramadan, time, moon

Bismillah. Alhamdulillahi rabbil-'alamin. Was-Salatu was-Salam 'ala Ashraful Anbiya Sayyidina Muhammad wa 'ala 'Alihi Muhammad.

---

**What should I do if on the 29 Shaban the sky is cloudy and I cannot see the Crescent of Shahri Ramadan?**

Although this issue has been discussed many times, it remains a matter which troubles most people. And according to my research, the most simple and clear instruction is given by the Imams of Ahlul Bayt. In following Hadith Imam Hussayn is teaching us a lesson for a lifetime,

> A'bu Abdullah(asws) said: "Count Shaban as twenty-nine days. So if it
> was cloudy, so wake up in the morning Fasting, and if it was clear and
> you can look, but you cannot see anything (new moon), so wake up in
> the morning not Fasting" (so 30 days of the Month of Shaban).
>
> <sup>Source: [Al Kafi – V 4 – The Book of Fasts Ch 6 H 9](https://hubeali.com/books/English-Books/AlKafiVol4/Al%20Kafi%20V4%20-%20The%20Book%20of%20Fasts%20(1).pdf)</sup>

Comment: This is very well known and should have been found by simple research, you even have mentioned the answer within the question. We have a hadith from the Prophet ﷺ which says the same see e.g. https://sunnah.com/muslim/13/21.

Comment: @UmH, please, provide a commentary for this Hadith. Post an answer.